# Javascript flipclock countdown generates incorrect date format

Tags: javascript, date, flipclock

I'm working on a website were I'd like to use a countdown to a special event. I've now installed the flipclock.js script and it's up and working. But, it generates incorrect date formats, like attached image:

[image: flipclock error]

As you can see, the days, minutes and seconds are working as expected, but the "hour" is showing 93. I've used the following code to implement the flipclock.js:

```
var date = new Date(2018, 11, 8, 12, 0, 0);
var now = new Date();
var diff = (date.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000;
console.log(date);
var clock;
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  autoStart: false,  
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
}
}
});
clock.setTime(diff);
clock.setCountdown(true);
clock.start();
```

Does anyone know why it's doing like this? I haven't changed anything in the

Comment: Have you tried setting the time variable as the first parameter in the constructor? `$('.clock').FlipClock(diff, { ...`? http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter I also noted that the date variables gets different timezones (At least for me)

Comment: @NoLifeKing—timezone is irrelevant here, both Dates will use the host offset.

Comment: @RobG When I tried it in my console, I got different offsets. https://itssimple.se/share/u/multinet/chrome_2018-08-02_11-02-52.png

Comment: @NoLifeKing—because one is in daylight saving for your host and one isn't. They are both host system offsets. So the calculation may be wrong by 1 hour with respect to local time, but that doesn't account for why the hours are 93 instead of something from 0 to 23.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, sorry. I just got confused. Let's get back to topic. :) Corneliatt, Have you tried in different browsers, if it's the same problem?

Comment: I found a comment on GitHub that have a similar problem when setting the time like your example. https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/204#issuecomment-134059706

Comment: Thanks NoLifeKing, that solved the problem! Have been searching for hours without finding a solution... Looked in the wrong places I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still looking for the solution... Here's the content of the link that [NoLifeKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025823/nolifeking) refers to in the comments section.

It looks like this issue occurs if you do the following:

```
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    'autoStart': false,
    'clockFace': 'DailyCounter',
    'countdown': true,
});
clock.setTime(diff);
clock.start();
```

as opposed to what is done below:

```
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    'autoStart': true,
    'clockFace': 'DailyCounter',
    'countdown': true,
});
```